# Battle Nations buildings and units are all invisible

Tags: macos, battle-nations

There's an [item on the Z2 website](http://z2.com/support/battle-nations/technical-issues/a-lot-of-my-units-buildings-are-invisible/) which says:

> With the new 3.0 update, a new 50 MB client was introduced.  Upon
>   booting it up, you may notice that several units and buildings are
>   invisible.  This is normal as the game downloads the remaining
>   graphics in the background.  Once the client is done playing catch up,
>   everything should look fine.

However, everything is not fine.  Since yesterday, all buildings (and units in battles) are invisible.  I'm using MacOS.  I've had the game running for an hour or two and not one building has appeared.   My outpost looks like a barren wasteland (albeit with some floating produce icons--the only way I can find my farms now!).

Edit: five days later, there's no solution in sight.  Z2 support said this is a known issue on iOS but not Mac OS X, and suggested reinstalling the game "several times."  It still doesn't work, and I haven't the slightest idea why.

Oh, and what's my question?  **Has anyone else seen this problem or similar and/or has an idea how to fix it?**

Comment: So, what's the question?

Comment: What can I do about this?  Is anyone else having the same problem?  I did also file a support ticket on the Z2 site, and will post again if they say anything helpful....

Comment: Then you might want to edit that request for solutions into your **question**. As it stands right now, you've only stated that there is a bug that the developers claim to have fixed that you are still experiencing. There is no question to answer. You might want to (re)read our [about](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/about) and [help](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help) pages to better understand how our QA site operates.